# Trying to deep copy a structure in C, but I keep failing, any ideas?

Tags: c

So basically I'm trying to flip an `Image` structure I've made in C, however I keep mirroring it right down the middle. This clearly means that I'm overwriting the image as I'm flipping it, so my copy isn't working. Any ideas on how I should be doing this??

Here's the code where I define my structure:

```
struct Image {
    int width, height;  // Width (=no. columns) and height (=no. rows) of the image.
    int **pixels;       // pixels[row][col] for each one
};
```

And this is the code where I attempt to flip it:

```
void flipImage(struct Image *img)
{
    struct Image *imgCopy = (struct Image *)malloc(sizeof(struct Image));
    memcpy(imgCopy, img, sizeof(struct Image));
    printf("done with copy");

    int row, col;
    for (row = 0; row < img->height; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < img->width; col++)
            imgCopy->pixels[row][col] = img->pixels[row][img->width - col - 1];

    outputFlippedImage(imgCopy);
}
```

I thought that `memcpy` was used to essentially deep copy things, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Kind of lost as to what to attempt next. I've sat here for the past hours scratching my head :///

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to get the deep copy working, up still have had no luck :( This is what I'm trying now, still yielding the wrong results. To clarify I'm trying to flip an image like so:

`123` -> `321`

As in flipping it from left to right. Here's my latest attempt:

```
void flipImage(struct Image *img)
{
    struct Image *imgCopy = malloc(sizeof(struct Image));
    *imgCopy = *img;

    memcpy(&imgCopy->height, &img->height, sizeof(img->height));
    memcpy(&imgCopy->width, &img->width, sizeof(img->width));
    memcpy(&imgCopy->pixels, &img->pixels, sizeof(img->pixels));
    printf("done with copy");

    int row, col;
    for (row = 0; row < img->height; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < img->width; col++)
            imgCopy->pixels[row][col] = img->pixels[row][img->width - col - 1];

    outputFlippedImage(imgCopy);
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: @Jabberwocky This is it really; I have code where I write the image to a file and read an image to a file but that's not really relevant. :)

Comment: The same way you would swap any pair of values `a` and `b`, with `temp = a; a = b; b = temp;` and by iterating to *half* the width (or you swap them back again).

Comment: `imgCopy->pixels[row][col] = img->pixels[row][img->width-col-1];` Just trace it in a debugger. Look at the range of values for `col` and `img->width-col-1`. They cross over at  some point and then you are just copying the same bytes again. You need to swap each pair of pixels via a temp variable.

Comment: You are misunderstandings pointers. Before dealing with image, write an exercise where you deal with a string.

Comment: To prepare a [mre], create a program that works with a very small image, perhaps just 1 row by 2 pixels. Show the data in the image before flipping it. Show the data in the image after flipping. Show the data you expect instead.

Comment: `memcpy()` desn't work for overlapping objects, in this case you should use `memmove()` (see https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/). But anyway it could fail unless your object pointers don't address linearly the object. The best solution is to craft a loop that allows the position swap, using an intermediate memory, to be completely safe.

Comment: The phrase “however I keep mirroring it right down the middle” is unclear. The question states “I'm trying to flip an image structure,” so mirroring it right down the middle seems correct: flipping and mirroring down the middle are the same thing. Edit the question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: You have not allocated memory for a "deep copy". You have only allocated memory for a shallow copy.

Comment: `memcpy(imgCopy, img, sizeof(struct Image));` copies the bytes directly in `img` to the bytes in `imgCopy`. It does not copy any bytes pointed to by pointers within `img`. It is a shallow copy, not a deep copy. To make a deep copy, you must write code that allocates new memory for `imgCopy`. It must allocate new space for the pointers pointed to by `pixels` and set `pixels` to point to that space. Then, since those are also pointers, it must allocate new space for for the data they point to and set all the pointers to point to that new space.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Copying half the width is incorrect because the goal here is to make a separate copy, not to flip in place.

Comment: You could combine a deep copy with an in-place flip.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I updated my question to show what I meant by flipping and added what I've been tried to do since you kindly gave your advice. Sorry for the dumb questions, I'm so used to OOP!! :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You do not allocate a copy of the `pixel` array, nor do you allocate copies of the individual scanlines pointed to by the `pixel` array.  Your copy and the original structure share the same data so the modification you perform on the copy is actually performed on the source image too.

Here is a modified version:

```
struct Image {
    int width, height;  // Width (=no. columns) and height (=no. rows) of the image.
    int **pixels;       // pixels[row][col] for each one
};

void flipImage(const struct Image *img)
{
    struct Image *imgCopy = malloc(sizeof(*imgCopy));
    imgCopy->width = img->width;
    imgCopy->height = img->height;
    imgCopy->pixels = calloc(img->rows, sizeof(*imgCopy->pixels));
    for (int row = 0; row < img->rows; row++) {
        imgCopy->pixels[row] = malloc(img->cols * sizeof(*imgCopy->pixels[i]));
        for (col = 0; col < img->width; col++)
            imgCopy->pixels[row][col] = img->pixels[row][img->width - col - 1];
        }
    }
    outputFlippedImage(imgCopy);

    // free copy.
    for (int row = 0; row < img->rows; row++) {
        free(imgCopy->pixels[row]);
    }
    free(imgCopy->pixels);
    free(imgCopy);
}
```

I would recommend using separate functions to clone, flip and free image structures.